# Bean validation: at least one element of a list must have one field filled

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

I have a list of lets say `Car` objects. Each car has a `miles` member.
I need to validate (using Hibernate Validator) that at least one car in my list has a not null `miles` member. The best solution would be an annotation that would apply to all the elements of a collection, but would validate in the context of the whole collection.

I have two questions:

- Is there already an annotation for this (I do not know of any)?
- If there is no annotation for this, is there a way to create an generic annotation? 
  I thought of specifiyng the name of the field that has to be not null at least for one element in the list, then I can apply this not only for `Car` classes.

  ```
  public class VechicleTransport {

      @AtLeastOneNotNull( fieldName = "miles" )
      private List<Car> carList;
  }


  public class Car {

    private Double miles;

      ....
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such annotation, You need to define custom constraint annotations and define your validation logic inside it.
Like
Defining custom constraint annotation `AtLeastOneNotNull`

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy=AtLeastOneNotNullValidator.class)

public @interface AtLeastOneNotNull{
 String message() default "Your error message";
 Class<!--?-->[] groups() default {};
 Class<!--? extends Payload-->[] payload() default {};
}
```

Defining validator for custom annotation.

```
public class AtLeastOneNotNullValidator implements ConstraintValidator<AtLeastOneNotNull, object=""> {

 @Override
 public void initialize(AtLeastOneNotNull constraint) {

 }

 @Override
 public boolean isValid(Object target, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    // Add logic to check if atleast one element have one field
 }
}
```

[**Link**](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2009/02/getting-started-with-jsr-303-bean.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know about custom annotations, probably a reflection in the isValid method would then make it work for any field. Thank you!